# Problem with the perturbation method applying to the nonlinear system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

There is a system of equations with initial conditions:
$$ \begin{cases} \dot x = y + a \cdot x \cdot y, \quad x(0) = 1, \\ \dot y = - x - b\cdot x \cdot y, \quad y(0) = 0;\end{cases} $$
where $a$ and $b$ are small parameters with the same order.
I have to apply perturbation approach to this system, and to find the solution in the second order of $a$ and $b$.
My problem: small corrections of different orders can be in resonance, and the small corrections will not be small when $a$ and $b$ go to $0$. I have to demand the absence of resonances, and to satisfy this requiring by frequency corrections. First, I will show what I do:$$$$The zeroth order:$$x(t)\approx x_{0}(t)\\y(t) \approx y_{0}(t)\\  \begin{cases} \dot x_{0}(t)=y_{0}(t),\quad x_{0}(0)=1,\\ \dot y_{0}(t)=-x_{0}(t), \quad y_{0}(0)=0; \end{cases} $$ The first order: $$x(t)\approx x_{0}(\omega t)+x_{1}(t)\\y( t) \approx y_{0}(\omega t) + y_{1}(t)\\ \omega = 1 + \omega_{1}\\ \begin{cases} \dot x_{1}(t)=y_{1}(t) + a \cdot x_{0}(\omega t) \cdot y_{0} (\omega t) - \omega_{1} \cdot x_{0}'(\omega t),\quad x_{1}(0)=0,\\ \dot y_{1}(t)=-x_{1}(t)-b \cdot x_{0}(\omega t) \cdot y_{0}(\omega t)-\omega_{1} \cdot y_{0}'(\omega t), \quad y_{1}(0)=0; \end{cases}\\Resonance \quad abscence \quad condition: \omega_{1}=0 $$ The second order:$$x(t) \approx x_{0}(\omega t) + x_{1}(\omega t) + x_{2}(t) \\ y(t) \approx y_{0}(\omega t) + y_{1}(\omega t) + y_{2}(t) \\ \omega = 1 + \omega_{1} + \omega_{2} = 1 + \omega_{2} \\ \begin{cases} \dot x_{2}(t) = y_{2}(t) + a \cdot (x_{0}(\omega t) \cdot y_{1} (\omega t) + x_{1}(\omega t) \cdot y_{1}(\omega t))-\omega_{2} \cdot x_{0}'(\omega t), \quad x_{2}(0)=0, \\ \dot y_{2}(t) = -x_{2}(t) - b \cdot (x_{0}(\omega t) \cdot y_{1} (\omega t) + x_{1}(\omega t) \cdot y_{1}(\omega t))-\omega_{2} \cdot y_{0}'(\omega t), \quad y_{2}(0)=0; \end{cases} \\ Resonance \quad abscence \quad condition: \quad ? \\  $$ For each order I have a system of equations with eigen frequence $= 1$. So, $\omega_{2}$ is not enaugh to satisfy resonance absence. The question is: how can I avoid the resonances?

Comment: Could you add some paragraphs on how the resonance manifests in your perturbation calculations? (I changed to "approach", as there are several perturbation methods and it is not clear what kind you want to use.) Did you consider to transform the system into polar coordinates and do the perturbation for those?

Comment: Lutz Lehmann, I added to my question what I do. And what kinds of perturbation theory exist?)

Comment: As said, you could consider polar coordinates. Then there is the method of multiple time scales, for some linear problems there is the WKB approximation, some homotopy methods,...

Comment: I think that your insight into the first order is wrong, the perturbation term has frequency 2, there is no resonance with the eigenfrequency of the left side or homogeneous equation. You get unavoidable resonance in the second order equations where the perturbation will have frequency 3 and 1. The question is if one can absorb these resonant terms into a frequency perturbation, partially or fully. The method of multiple time scales does this in a systematic way.

Comment: Why the first order is wrong? Yes, there is no resonancem, but this step is needed to show the first correction of the $\omega$ is $0$ (I have to use it in the second order).

Comment: Thanks for the multiple timescale method. I don't know about it, I'll try to find something) But I don't want just to resolve this system, I want to understand, how to use perturbation approach in this case. And could you write the names of differernt perturbation methods? I want to find them :-)

Comment: Oh... One more thanks for multiple time scales method))At first I didn't realized, that it is one of the perturbation methods)

Comment: I tried to apply multy scales method. Seems like I do it wrong.

Comment: I represented: $$x(t) \approx x_{0}(t, t_{2}) + x_{1}(t, t_{2}) + x_{2}(t,t_{2}) \\ x(t) \approx y_{0}(t, t_{2}) + y_{1}(t, t_{2}) + y_{2}(t,t_{2}) \\ t_{2} \sim a^2 t \sim b^2 t $$ It gived me four conditions for only two functions of $ t_{2}$. How should I increese the number of arbitrary functions to satisfy all conditions? May be I can add another time scale...